# The database cannot be opened because it is version 839. This server supports version 782 and earlier. A downgrade path is not supported

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2015

I made a C# project that contains a local database (Microsoft SQL Database Server) (mdf) in my pc that works totally fine. but whenever i use my laptop to run it, it gives me this error:

**The database 'C:(the path)\CALENDER.MDF' cannot be opened because it is version 839. This server supports version 782 and earlier. A downgrade path is not supported.**

this error appears every time i try to refresh server explorer. i need it to work in my laptop because i use it to make a class presentation.

[image]

Comment: You have to open it in a newer version of sql server and then save it as the older version

Comment: Your laptop is running an older version of SQL Server. Try upgrading it to the same version as your desktop.

Comment: @Mihai i have installed sql server 2014 express

Comment: I think that version 839 is from Sql Server 2016 CTP3.0

Comment: @Steve i will install Sql Server 2016 CTP3.0 and check if it will solve the problem.

Comment: Caution with CTP software.... why don't you try to script your database and then reimport from the script?

Comment: @Steve sorry i dont understand how to do it or how it works

Comment: Using Sql Server Management Studio on the export PC connect and right click on your database. Choose Tasks, Generate Scripts. Choose your objects to export and check in the advanced options to export Data and Schema with Scripting for Sql Server 2014. Save your SQL file and now you have a series of Sql commands that could be executed on the destination PC rebuilding your db

Comment: i installed SQL Server 2016 and it didnt solve the problem, something must be edited from settings i believe

Comment: @Steve thanks you gave me the idea about server management studio and i learned how to use it and solved the problem. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a long researches and tries i figured how to solve this issue. its a bit complicated. i converted the mdf database to and access(mdb) and import data from the mdb to a new mdf database.

these are the steps:

1. Create an empty access (mdb) database.
2. using SQL Server 2016 CTP3.0 Import and Export Data: import data from database which is calander.mdf in my case to the new access database (mdb).
3. now in the destination pc, create a new vs form and add a new empty mdf database.
4. using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio ( Databases > right click new database > type database name and click OK.)
5. Right mouse click on your database name and hover to Tasks and then select the Import Data.
6. select the data source Microsoft Access (Microsoft Access Database Engine) and browse to the access database and click next.
7. in Destination select Net Framework Data Provider For SqlServer and type the connection string for the new empty created mdf database. then click next and finish.
8. Copy the new mdf database To your project file
9. now you got the new database filled with data and all is left is go to your main project and delete the database and then add new existing item and browse to the new database and log file and clock ok. and the database should work

WORKED WITH ME !!!!!!

[image]

Comment: Well, that's a long way and I am glad that it works for you. Still I haven't figured out to which database file applies the 839 version number. If you run this query on your 2016 CTP what is the version number returned? _select DATABASEPROPERTYEX('master', 'version')_

Comment: @Steve i just did it says 782, well i dont think there is upper version than SQL Server 2016 CTP 3.0

Comment: uhm strange, this is the same number of mine and I am pretty sure to have just Sql Server 2014 installed

Comment: @Steve Most people have the problem of having database version 782 and The server supports version 706 and earlier. i didnt even find anything about 839.